# Logout Laravel no funciona

Tags: laravel

Tengo la función en LoginController, la he puesto tal y como esta en un tutorial que estoy siguiendo.

```
    <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Login Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles authenticating users for the application and
    | redirecting them to your home screen. The controller uses a trait
    | to conveniently provide its functionality to your applications.
    |
    */

    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after login.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = '/';

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest', ['except' => 'logout']);
        // $this->middleware($this->guestMiddleware(), ['except' => 'logout']);        
    }

    public function getLogout()
    {
        return $this->logout();
    }

    public function logout()
    {
        Auth::guard($this->getGuard())->logout();

        return redirect(property_exists($this, 'redirectAfterLogout') ? $this->redirectAfterLogout : '/');
    }

}
```

El error que me arroja es este: 
**"Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Auth\Auth' not found"**

Mi versión de Laravel es 5.7.

Comment: en tu LoginController tienes `use Auth`?

Comment: sip, de hecho el login funciona y todo, sólo es el logout

Comment: Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Auth\Auth en el error se puede ver que se repite Auth, no estoy muy segura de por qué sucede si lo he hecho tal cual, tal vez sea la version

Answer (score 3):

Me parece que no estas incorporando correctamente la clase necesaria. Si nos fijamos en la [**documentación oficial**](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/authentication#authenticating-users) nos dice que debemos agregar `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;`. Entonces tu controlador debería quedar algo así:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
  public function logout()
  {
    Auth::logout();
  }
}
```

Saludos!

Comment: muchas gracias, pensé que Laravel lo añadia pero ya esta bien, gracias!!! pero... después de que incorporé la clase que me indicas, ahora obtengo este -> Method App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController::getGuard does not exist.

Comment: Solo debes usar `Auth::logout();` como lo indico en la respuesta.NO uses `getGuard()`

Comment: eso me funcionó, me podrias explicar el por que, estoy siguiendo un tutorial y varias veces he tenido este tipo de inconvenientes

Comment: Deberías revisar en que versión está basado el tutorial, Probablemente esté usando una mas antigua. También puede ser que haya realizado alguna modificación en los providers y no te hayas percatado. Pero te recomiendo usar la info oficial. Puedes ver los tutoriales para hacerte una idea del proceso, y luego recurrir a la pagina de Laravel para investigar y aprender el mejor modo de hacerlo. Saludos!